# Converting dictionary into string

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

```
d={'a':'Apple','b':'ball','c':'cat'}
```

The above dictionary I have and I want my Output like the below-mentioned result

```
res="a=Apple,b=ball,c=cat"
```

Is it possible in a pythonic way then please answer it I have tried various method but did not get desired output?

Comment: what did you try? please share your past work

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Read your dictionary as key/value pairs ([`dict.items()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items)) and then just format them in a string you like:

```
d = {'a': 'Apple', 'b': 'ball', 'c': 'cat'}

res = ",".join("{}={}".format(*i) for i in d.items())  # a=Apple,c=cat,b=ball
```

The order, tho, cannot be guaranteed for a [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict), use [`collections.OrderedDict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) if order is important.

Comment: @SamreshKumarJha - Prior to Python 3.6 (at least on CPython) dictionaries were not guaranteed to preserve order. In fact, they are only guaranteed to preserve insert order in CPython implementation of Python 3.6 - interpreter wide guarantee comes only with Python 3.7. Everything not guaranteed to run on CPython 3.6+ or a general Python 3.7+ interpreter should not count on `dict` being ordered.

Comment: Slight nitpick: `join` can take a list/tuple comprehension, no need wrap it in an extra layer of parenthesis

Answer (score 5):

One way is to iterate via `dict.items` and use multiple `str.join` calls.

```
d = {'a':'Apple','b':'ball','c':'cat'}

res = ','.join(['='.join(i) for i in d.items()])

# 'a=Apple,b=ball,c=cat'
```

If you need items ordered by key, use `sorted(d.items())`.

Answer (score 2):

```
def format_dict(d):
    vals = list(d.values())
    return "={},".join(d.keys()).format(*vals) + "={}".format(vals[-1])

d = {'a': 'Apple', 'b': 'ball', 'c': 'cat'}
format_dict(d)  # -> 'a=Apple,b=ball,c=cat'
```

This joins all the keys into a large string containing replacement fields that we then format passing the dict values as args. There wasn't a trailing replacement field so we concatenate the last value in the dictionary to our large string.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming here looking for a way to explicitly extract the dictionary keys and values (e.g. if further formatting is required):

```
d = {'a':'Apple','b':'ball','c':'cat'}
res = ','.join(f'{k}={v}' for k, v in d.items())  
# --> a=Apple, b=ball, c=cat
```

(uses python 3.6+ f-strings)